# Import ColorContrastChecker not working in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Trying to implement ColorContrastChecker in React using the color-contrast-checker plugin.

import {ColorContrastChecker} from "color-contrast-checker" is not working in ReactJS

```
import {ColorContrastChecker} from "color-contrast-checker";
var cc=new ColorContrastChecker();
var color1 = "#FFFFFF";
var color2 = "#000000;
if (ccc.isLevelAA(color1, color2, 14)) {
      alert("Valid Level AA");
} else {
    alert("Invalid Contrast");
  }
}

Error: define cannot be used indirect
▶ 3 stack frames were collapsed.
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/pru10504/Documents/Indoors-WebApp/webpack/bootstrap:781
778 | };
779 | 
780 | // Execute the module function
> 781 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, 
hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
  | ^  782 | 
783 | // Flag the module as loaded
784 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/Users/pru10504/Documents/Indoors-WebApp/webpack/bootstrap:149
146 |       );
147 |       hotCurrentParents = [];
148 |   }
> 149 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
  | ^  150 | };
151 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
152 |   return {
View compiled
```

Reference Link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/color-contrast-checker

Comment: Maybe is just a typo? ColorContastChecker != ColorContrastChecker

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think @joseluismurillorios probably has the right answer in that comment. It could help to include the exact error message as well.

Comment: @joseluismurillorios Corrected it to ColorContrastChecker, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the brackets and it works fine now.

```
import ColorContrastChecker from 'color-contrast-checker'
```